# Probability of if statement evaluating as true

Tags: probability, algorithms

Given the algorithm to compute the maximum of an array of numbers. Assuming that the numbers appear in the array in random order.

What is the probability that the condition 'if ($a[i]>$max)'

1) is true exactly one time?

2) is true $n$ times?

I figured the answer to 1)  is $\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}$ and 2) $\frac{1}{n!}$

Those are just my thoughts. I can't seem to justify them.

Comment: I suppose you mean to ask for how many $i$ the condition $a[i]>\max_{j<i}a[j]$ is true; is that correct? If so, then your answers are correct.

Comment: Its part of a pseudocode algorithm. Its the 'if' statement in the algo (see edited answer)

Comment: And thanks. Also, why is it correct? @TashiWalde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a_i > \max_{j < i} (a_j)$ to be true exactly once, that means that there is only one time where a value in the array is larger than all of the values that come before it. Note that (I assume) $a_1 > \max$ is considered to always evaluate to true, so your check has to *fail* for all $i > 2$, which means that $a_2 < a_1$, and also $a_3 < a_1$, and so forth, i.e. $a_1$ is the maximum of the array. What's the probability of that happening for a random array? Well, there are $n!$ ways to arrange the elements of the array, but $1 \times (n-1)!$ ways to put the maximum as $a_1$ and then randomly permute the rest. So the probability of that happening is $\frac{(n-1)!}{n!} = \frac{1}{n}$.

For the condition to be true $n$ times, it has to be true for *every* element - $a_1 > \emptyset$, $a_2 > a_1$, $a_3 > \max(a_1, a_2) = a_2$, and so forth. In other words, the array has to be sorted in ascending order. How many ways can you do that? Just the one. So the probability of it happening is $\frac{1}{n!}$.